# Navigate context menu with nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

Im using nightwatchjs and having some difficulties with selecting a text and triggering a right-click and navigate a context menu that I built. This image is an example of what im trying to achieve. Select the 1957 text, right click, nagivate to down to toolkit, then nagivate right, and right again, and click search zone.
[image]

My nightwatchjs code is as follow:

```
    it('Api test call', function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://sandbox.com/apiTest.html')
            .pause()
        browser.expect.element('#zoneId').text.to.equal('1957')
        .moveToElement('#zoneId')
        .mouseButtonClick('right')
        .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
        .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
        .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
        .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
        .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
        .keys(browser.Keys.RIGHT_ARROW)
        .keys(browser.Keys.RIGHT_ARROW)
        .end();
    });
```

Right now it doesn't work, it just loads the page but nothing gets selected and navigation does not happen.
Anyone can advise me if this is possible or how I can make it work?
Thank you.

Comment: till which step the test is executed successfully ?

Comment: until moveToElement, i get error like `Error: Unknown property: "moveToElement"`

Comment: Which browser you are working with ?

Comment: chrome browser v 90.0.4430

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. I have replaced `browser.expect.element('#zoneId').text.to.equal('1957')` with `.assert.containsText('#zoneId', '1957')`. And also added xoffset and offset to `moveToElement`.

```
it('Api test call', function(browser) {
  browser
    .url('http://sandbox.com/apiTest.html')
    .assert.containsText('#zoneId', '1957')
    .moveToElement('#zoneId', 10, 10)
    .mouseButtonClick('right')
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.RIGHT_ARROW)
    .pause(1000)
    .keys(browser.Keys.RIGHT_ARROW)
    .end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I added that code, and it does right-click (not on 1957 though). However, the down arrow keys do not seem to work. This is how it looks and stops https://i.ibb.co/ygLH6Yc/Screen-Shot-2021-04-30-at-2-46-34-PM.png

Comment: adjust the x offset and y offset to reach your element and add some pause between the keyboard presses. Updated the code. refer this URL https://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveToElement.html#apimethod-page to know how x and y offset works.

Comment: yea that seems to work and selecting the right value, also the right click works but the keys  DOWN_ARROW is not working. This is how it stops https://i.ibb.co/PmpnqJD/Screen-Shot-2021-04-30-at-3-01-13-PM.png

Comment: Can you use `.keys(browser.Keys.ARROW_DOWN)` instead of `.keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)`

Comment: Just tried ".keys(this.Keys.ARROW_DOWN)" & ".keys(this.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)" and those trigger an error message at the console "TypeError: Cannot read property 'DOWN_ARROW' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry please replace this with browser. It was a typo. `.keys(browser.Keys.ARROW_DOWN)`

Comment: Got you, I just tried that and it still doesn't trigger a key down. However, from the console, the test does pass "OK. 3  total assertions passed"

Comment: Try with the combination of keys like start with the right arrow key than the down key or any other keys. because the command you are using is correct.

Comment: thanks, i tried a different combination of directions, it doesn't do it. Like you said, syntax wise looks correct, output on console is OK, but it doesn't really work. I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do might not be possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231802/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-jfr01).